# How to access another control's viewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a CustomControl B, which uses a DataContext/MVVM (viewModelB). Now I want to bind one Property of my CustomControl to another control A (uses viewModelA as DataContext).

So I have two Ideas:

1. Whenever PropA in viewModelA changes, I could directly update PropB in the viewModelB. But this creates a dependency between the viewModels, which seems ugly to me. Or is this a common way in the MVVM pattern and can't be avoided?
2. As an alternative I could think of a dependency property on CustomControlB and wire it to CustomControlA's viewModel by a binding, something like that:

   `<myControlB PropB={Binding ElementName=myControlA, Path=DataContext.PropA} />`.

   So far so good, but the dependency property is defined on the view now. How should I visualize it?

   - a) Should I transfer the value (from the property wrapper) to viewModelB and bind to it from viewB's XAML code?
   - b) Or should I directly update the view from B's codeBehind? Would this be still a proper MVVM "style"?

Which of the options would you recommend?

regards

Andreas

Comment: You could use Attached property from one control.. Have you tried with that?

Comment: Are these controls in the same view?

Comment: @Sankarann Could you please your idea in more detail? I don't see how I could solve that with an attached property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as ViewModelA doesn't actively update ViewModelB, there is no real coupling between the two viewmodels. What I mean is that if your main view model (which knows both viewmodels) is the one that wires up the binding, the view models are still loosely coupled.

So to me any of these are fine:

- Bind directly to myControlA.DataContext.PropA from XAML
- Have the `MainViewModel` register for `ViewModelA`'s property changed event and modify `ViewModelB`'s property as necessary. Here `MainViewModel` knows about the two view models, but they know nothing of each other.

Comment: thx for sharing your thoughts. Unfortunately I don't have a MainViewModel (legacy project, we just start using MVVM).